# tensorflow: Is it possible to feed the batch of images with different size?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

If I have different sizes images for training, is it possible to feed them directly into the tensorflow network without resizing into the same size e.g.(256,256)?

Comment: No, at least not easily.

Comment: I find that [spatial pyramid pooling net](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729v4.pdf) can deal with any size input, can it be possible in tensorflow?